# Tag for the time of human history directly prior to Jesus' ministry

Tags: discussion, tags

I was thinking this question [What part did the Psalms play in Jewish worship?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/59258/what-part-did-the-psalms-play-in-jewish-worship) could use a better tag than [john-the-baptist](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/john-the-baptist) since it's not really about him, but just the times he lived in.  It's not early Church because it's pre-pentecost.  Is there a good name for this period of human history?

Comment: I think the question is off-topic, so I'm not sure we need a tag for it. And "history" is still valid.

Comment: The four centuries between Malachi and John the Baptist is of interest historically  but scripture does not comment on that period so I do not see how it could be the focus of questions about Christianity.

Comment: @nigel All those Maccabees books were written in that period YBMV

Comment: I am only familiar with the canon of the 66 books, so perhaps a tag is needed if there are other books in which people would want to take an interest. And 'YBMV' is also unfamiliar.

Comment: Your Bible May Vary,  1 and 2 Maccabees are canonical for most Christians and 3 and 4 Maccabees are canonical for a large handful.  I think Wisdom was written during that period too.  The period in Judaism, might be called Maccabaen, not sure.

Comment: If we are asking about culture, then the time of John the Baptist overlapped with the time of Jesus' ministry, and there would have been no difference culturally at all. If such a tag is necessary I would suggest "new-testament-times" (and corresponding "old-testament-times", though the latter covers a ridiculous amount of cultural time).